# awk regex matches wrong?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

Playing around with awk I noticed this behavior:

```
[root@ror6ax3 ~]# grep open * | awk '$2 ~ /opens*/ {print $0}'
install.log:Installing openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64
install.log:Installing openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64
install.log:Installing openssh-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
install.log:Installing openssh-clients-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
install.log:Installing openssh-server-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
install.log:Installing b43-openfwwf-5.2-4.el6.noarch
[root@ror6ax3 ~]# grep open * | awk '$2 ~ /opens */ {print $0}'
install.log:Installing openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64
install.log:Installing openssh-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
install.log:Installing openssh-clients-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
install.log:Installing openssh-server-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
```

Why would `opens*` match `openldap` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` means 0 or more, so effecively 0 or more `s` characters. There's the documentation [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_28.html#IDX216), that says

> For example, `ph*' applies the`*' symbol to the preceding `h' and looks for matches of one`p' followed by any number of `h's. This also matches just`p' if no `h's are present.

In your case, you're doing `opens*` while you're probably expecting something like `opens+`, where `+` means "1 or more". Check out the docs on the `+` operator [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_28.html#IDX218)

Comment: Got it, I confused `*` with `+`.